# Why the order of object files is important for static libraries?

Tags: c, static-libraries, unix-ar

I create some files:

`file1.c
file2.c
file3.c`

I compile them using `gcc -c file1.c` and i did the same for other files, and i get object files. Later i used `ar` tool to create static library.

Everythink works correctly, but `ar` has option

`ar -m -a file.o lib.a filetomove.o`

to move object files in library, why order of object files is important? Please, show me example where object files must be in  correct order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is less and less of a problem as time goes on, but for a long time linkers were single pass. That means if a symbol was defined in a.o and referenced in b.o, the linker had to "see" b.o *before* a.o or it would never find a definition for the reference.

In other circumstances, sometimes a "default" function is provided in a library that is linked last. This is a popular technique in embedded systems development. You can provide an override function by linking it in a static library or object module, but if you don't, the last library will provide a symbol that satisfies the linker.

Comment: Whether the use of threads may require the correct order of object files? File a.o dont use any file from b.o.

Comment: If the two files don't refer to each other, there is no ordering dependency. Threads won't make a difference, unless you refer to a specific thread *library,* in which case it will follow the same rules that other libraries follow.

Comment: What if file a.o uses references from b.o and b.o uses references from a.o?

Comment: Then you have a circular dependency problem. Generally you can solve it by linking one of the files twice. `ld a.o b.o a.o ...`

Comment: It would be correct if i use <pre> ar -s <code> it put index into library, and allows routines in the library to call each other without regard to their placement in the the archive.

Comment: But if linker are not single pass now, why is the order of multiple .a or .so files still an issue? Why do we still care about their linking order?